# Create an Expanding, Key Referenced Array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an object type I want to create:

```
private LeagueItem[] leagues;

public class LeagueItem
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tier { get; set; }
    public string points { get; set; }
    public bool fresh { get; set; }
    public bool streak { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to be able to add items to this array as my program iterates:

```
foreach (var league in results.Children())
{
    leagues[league.id] = new LeagueItem()
    {
        name = league.name,
        tier = league.tier + " " + league.entries[0].division,
        points = league.entries[0].leaguePoints,
        fresh = league.entries[0].isFreshBlood,
        streak = league.entries[0].isHotStreak,
    };
}
```

You'll notice that I want the array to have key-indexes assigned from the ID of each league. This is because I need to access the league data based on these IDs, such as `leagues[###].name`.

The problem I am having is that this doesn't work. Arrays require you to set the size when you initialize. I wont know the size of the array in advance, and the IDs for the leagues can be a wide variety of characters. What would be the best and simplest way of accomplishing what I am trying to do?

Comment: Tip: Use a [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and *not* an array for an "expanding sequences" - it is a rare case when I create arrays explicitly. Then `theList.Add(..)` can be used to add new items. For "keys" and not "indices" a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is probably more appropriate, but such discards order: use the correct data-type for the operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary, this makes the *array* index-based and a dictionary can be extended with more items. The key of the dictionary represents your league identifier, the value is your league object. Try something like this:

```
// declare the league dictionary
private IDictionary<int, LeagueItem> leagues; // assuming the league ID is a number

// define the league dictionary
leagues = new Dictionary<int, LeagueItem>();

// add new leagues
foreach (var league in results.Children())
{
    leagues.Add(
        league.id,
        new new LeagueItem()
        {
            name = league.name,
            tier = league.tier + " " + league.entries[0].division,
            points = league.entries[0].leaguePoints,
            fresh = league.entries[0].isFreshBlood,
            streak = league.entries[0].isHotStreak,
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `Dictionary<int, T>`.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst: Yes, but it is exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an List for the scenario you've specified.

```
List<LeagueItem> leagues = new List<LeagueItem>();

foreach (var league in results.Children())
{
    leagues.Add(new LeagueItem()
    {
        name = league.name,
        tier = league.tier + " " + league.entries[0].division,
        points = league.entries[0].leaguePoints,
        fresh = league.entries[0].isFreshBlood,
        streak = league.entries[0].isHotStreak,
    });
}
```

To find a league item based on id, i would use Linq:

```
var league = leagues.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 10);
```

You could even replace the for loop with a Linq statement.